# Android: write bytes to image file on SD Card

Tags: android, file, encoding

I'm trying to create an image file on sd-card, building it from the bytes that a server is sending towards me after calling a web-service (basically: download file).
I managed to get "something" on the client-side, and try to write those bytes to a file, using:

```
FileOutputStream fOut = null;
BufferedOutputStream bOs = null;

try {
        fOut = new FileOutputStream(returnedFile);

        bOs = new BufferedOutputStream(fOut);

        bOs.write(bytesToWrite);

}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
} 
catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
finally {
        try {
            if (bOs != null) {
                bOs.close();
                fOut.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

but the image file is broken (its size is > 0kb, but broken).
I ended up opening that file on my computer with a text editor, and I saw that some of the initial file data (before being sent), differs from the final one. So I'm guessing that there is some kind of encoding misstakening or something like that.
I would appreciate an idea of how to make this work ( download image file from a web server, and open in on my phone).
PS. I can also change or get info about the server configuration, as it was configured by a friend of mine.
PS2. I should be able not to download only images, but any kind of file.

Comment: Are you sure that the response is not in Base64 ? I had this problem once, and Base 64 decoding solved it !

Comment: sry, updated pData.getBytes() was changed to bytesToWrite (the actual bytes that come from server)

Comment: @Skaard-Solo I haven't mention anywhere that the response is in Base64. Could you clarify me a little bit with what you meant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think It's better you encode the image to Base64 in your server, for example in PHP you can do it like this :

```
$type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($path);
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
```

And then in android you decode the Base64 string into your image file:

```
FileOutputStream fos = null;
try {

if (base64ImageData != null) {
    fos = context.openFileOutput("imageName.png", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    byte[] decodedString = android.util.Base64.decode(base64ImageData, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
    fos.write(decodedString);

    fos.flush();
    fos.close();

    }

} catch (Exception e) {

} finally {
    if (fos != null) {
        fos = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks to getting close to what I want, but the question is: Will I be able to make it work for downloading other kind of data except images (cause they work right now, the only problem is with the images) ?

Comment: Yes, I think you can encode/decode any file type (audio, image..) to/from base64

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure you have this permissions on your android manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

File stream is designed to work on local file storage rather than network connection. Use **URLConnection** class instead.

```
URL uri = new URL("Your Image URL");
URLConnection connection = uri.openConnection();
InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
//DO other stuff....
```

Comment: I am getting the bytes from server and use FileOutputStream to write to local storage. What is wrong with that? My problem is that the bytes coming out are not (probably) encoded the same way the server does or smth like that. The idea is that I succesfully write to file the bytes, but they are incorect, or at least, not properly "understood" to decode them right.